# Using && In an If Statement Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am trying to make a very basic console game of rock paper scissors. I'm not sure how to go about using && in `Swift 2.0`. I want to basically say:

```
if (computerChoice == rock && userChoice == paper) {

print("User wins")

}
```

Comment: Did you try it?  What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: ...have you put that in Xcode and seen what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Well you appear to have it setup correctly. You could set this up using an enumeration variable.

```
enum RPSOption {
   case Rock, Paper, Scissors
}
```

Then you just use it like so:

```
let computerChoice: RPSOption = RPSOption.Rock // or something else
let userChoice: RPSOption = RPSOption.Paper // or something else

if( computerChoice == .Rock && userChoice == .Paper ){
   // do something
}
// do similar if statements for other conditions
```